# Ganesh Visharjana in South India

Tags: ganesha

Is the tradition of Ganesh visharajana observed in South India and not in North India? Are there any puranic references to this?

Comment: I've also heard people saying that lord ganesha comes for 10 days and then the visarjana happens... Do you know the reason for 10 days? If not, you can also ask this in your question.